# AxiosError message Request failed with status code 401

Tags: mern

I was following the MERN AI Chatbot tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrHTcjSZQ1Y but encountered the following error when I try to sign up or login and i'm not sure how to resolve it:

api-communicator.ts:25
GET http://localhost:5000/api/v1/user/auth-status 401 (Unauthorized)

AuthContext.tsx:40  Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 401', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

This is my code for api-communicator.ts :

```
import axios from "axios";
export const loginUser = async (email: string, password: string) => {
  const res = await axios.post("/user/login", { email, password });
  if (res.status !== 200) {
    throw new Error("Unable to login");
  }
  const data = await res.data;
  return data;
};

export const signupUser = async (
  name: string,
  email: string,
  password: string
) => {
  const res = await axios.post("/user/signup", { name, email, password });
  if (res.status !== 201) {
    throw new Error("Unable to Signup");
  }
  const data = await res.data;
  return data;
};

export const checkAuthStatus = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get("/user/auth-status");
  if (res.status !== 200) {
    throw new Error("Unable to authenticate");
  }
  const data = await res.data;
  return data;
};

export const sendChatRequest = async (message: string) => {
  const res = await axios.post("/chat/new", { message });
  if (res.status !== 200) {
    throw new Error("Unable to send chat");
  }
  const data = await res.data;
  return data;
};

export const getUserChats = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get("/chat/all-chats");
  if (res.status !== 200) {
    throw new Error("Unable to send chat");
  }
  const data = await res.data;
  return data;
};

export const deleteUserChats = async () => {
  const res = await axios.delete("/chat/delete");
  if (res.status !== 200) {
    throw new Error("Unable to delete chats");
  }
  const data = await res.data;
  return data;
};

export const logoutUser = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get("/user/logout");
  if (res.status !== 200) {
    throw new Error("Unable to delete chats");
  }
  const data = await res.data;
  return data;
};
```

tried to restart server and also renamed api-communicator.ts but it didnt work